# How do I use jQuery's .each() to replace text / regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have this code right here:

```
var tweetText = $("#tweet_text").text();
var replaced = replace(tweetText);

document.getElementById("tweet_text").innerHTML = replaced;
```

It gets text from a text element, and highlights the mentions and URLS to make them clickable. 
Here is the `replace()` code:

```
function replace(text) {
    return text.replace(/([@#])([a-z\d_]+)/ig, function(_, marker, tag) {
        if (marker === "@")
            return '<a href="?r=site/twitterprofile&q=$1">' + "@" + tag + '</a>';
        return '<a href="?r=site/hashtag&q=$2">' + "#" + tag + '</a>';
    });
}
```

I have a long list of divs / tweets, and when I run `replace()` it only applies the pattern matching function to one div. 
To get around this, I thought of collecting all of the `#tweet_text`divs using `.each()`, and then applying the `replace()` function once it loops through.

Could somebody help me do that please?

Comment: see the doc for [each](http://api.jquery.com/each)

Comment: You want to change value of text box or content of the div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.your-tweet-class').each(function() {
    $(this).text( replace( $(this).text() ) );
});
```

You can remove the spaces, I just put them in for clarity.

Comment: i ended up using .html() because I was echoing html and not text. Everything works fine now though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) as follow.

> Set the HTML contents of **each** element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('.tweetClass').html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    return replace(oldHtml);
});
```